# Setting up a 2nd web application on another port

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, my-site, web-application, host-header

I have a Web application on SharePoint 2010 setup on Port 80.

I would like to set up another Web Application for My Sites on Port 81. I have followed all of the steps to do this and can successfully access a users My Site

Is there any way to remove :81 from the URL that is created. I know this would not appear if I created it on the original web application on port 80 but I need to create MySites in a separate web application as per Microsoft best recommendation.

So my questions are:

- Can I create a second web app on port 80 and how would I
  configure this? e.g. host header
- Is it OK to do this or does the 2nd web app need to be on a different
  port?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

If you have the proper DNS then its really easy.

Couple of options:

**Host headers:**

You can specify a host header when creating the web application which allows for multiple listeners on port 80

http://onlinecoder.blogspot.com/2012/10/setup-multiple-sharepoint-web.html

http://wwolfe.blogspot.com/2009/04/multiple-web-applications-on-port-80.html

**VIA ForeFront UAG**

deploy SharePoint web applications via Forefront Unified Access Gateway (UAG) in a topology in which the server running SharePoint Products and Technologies publishes multiple web applications on a single port.

[Publishing multiple SharePoint applications on a single port](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd857229.aspx)

You dont need to create the web application on 2nd port. If you have host header you will be fine.

Comment: Thanks for the info. The reason I am creating a 2nd Web app is for My Sites. So with this in mind, it is advisable to create My Sites on another web application using the same port? I would assume that when creating a 2nd web application for My Sites you would use a different port?

Comment: its really doesnot matter on which port you are creating the web apps. Only thing is sometime we dont want port number in our urls...to over come that problem we need a a host header /DNS.